# How would can I add a serial port (virtual) to AQEMU

Tags: operating-system, serial-port, virtual-machine, qemu

I am using the AQEMU gui for the first time, and tried to run a [mikeos](https://mikeos.sourceforge.net/) instance/vm. However, Mikeos requires a serial port for many applications I tried to add one, but in the selector COM was not an option.
[Image with com port options grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihfqg.png)
As I said, I have tried to add ports, as I said COM ports were not an option.
Any answers would be appreciated.

*I am running the latest version of kali linux (debian 12), on a potato laptop from 2013. Idk if this helps.*